# Draw 3D text being local THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I downloaded three.js, gltfloader.js to my pc, and run site with threejs scene, as a local file in opera.

To draw text using TextGeometry I need to load font using FontLoader, but the problem is that it loads font file using ajax, that is impossible for local files in opera.

What to do?

---

What if to modify my local GLTFLoader.js file, by just pasting there as a string plain text from my json font file and change httprequest function to read from that string?

Comment: There is [`.parse()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/FontLoader.parse) method of the `THREE.FontLoader()`. The same for `THREE.GLTFLoader()`.

Comment: @prisoner849 getting error while calling new THREE.TextBufferGeometry at three.js:851 can’t read property yMax of undefined

Comment: Parse method seems to work correct - returns object

Comment: @prisoner849 understood. I have to pass data from file to parse(), not the file name

Comment: @prisoner849 still getting that error.. I created a variable in js file, put the json file entire text into a single bracket(there is also one single bracket character in font data, I replaced it with \'). Do I still do something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: @prisoner849 I mean like `var data='stuff\'stuff';

Comment: @prisoner849 opera doesn’t support that flags, can’t run local server

Comment: I use this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210000/discussion-between-artur-and-prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 So, what it the sense of parse method then?

Answer (score 0):

*No chrome-need, no plugins, no flags*

So, with help prisoner849, I had to do this:

1. Create string variable and put the entire text from json font file here. **Attention!** There will be characters like `"\\"` or `"\""` or`"\r"`. Easiest way to deal with it, if you don’t need to use them, is just replace them with any non-conflicted character like `ї`
2. `var data=JSON.parse(your_variable);`
3. `var loader=new THREE.FontLoader(); var font=loader.parse(data);`
4. Use font in `TextGeometry`

[image]

Comment: Why not use sprites or planes with textures for these markers?

Comment: @prisoner849 You mean to draw 10 pngs from 0 to 9 and make from them numbers?

Comment: An easier option it to create 10 textures with writings "1mm", "2mm" and so on, and share them between sprites along axes. Thus one texture for 3 sprites. Except a single texture for "0mm".

Comment: I don’t think this is the easier option. The only difficult for me was the fact that I didn’t know how to use `Fontloader.parse()` and `JSON.parse()` method. Changing characters is also not a difficult, just press ctrl f and it will be fast

Comment: Okay, do as you wish, if you want more drawcalls for your scene. I don't insist :)